# I keep getting EOFError() in Komodo IDE 7.1

Tags: ftp, komodo-ide

Suddenly the publishing/synchronization feature in Komodo IDE 7.1 doesn't work anymore and when I click synchronize I keep getting `EOFError()`.

[image: screencap describing the problem]

I've been searching the net for hours now and couldn't find anything.

What caused this to start happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Either the FTP password has [expired](http://community.activestate.com/node/9133) or there's a [path](http://community.activestate.com/forum/publishing-does-not-sync-file-changes) issue.